# FileNotFound with .jar and JSSE

Tags: java, file, jsse

I am using JSSE and have the following code:

```
private static void setupServerKeystore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        mServerKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        mServerKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(iComputer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("res/server.public").getPath()), 
                            "pswd".toCharArray());
}


private static void setupClientKeyStore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
            mClientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
            mClientKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(iComputer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("res/client.private").getPath()),
                                   mPassphrase.toCharArray());
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
- iComputer
   - src
        - com
            - ...
        - res
            - server.public
            - client.private
```

Both of the URLs work within Eclipse and the client executes the handshake successfully. However, when I export this as a .jar file, I get a FileNotFoundException:

```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> file:/Users/Zack/Downloads/iComputer.jar!/res/server.public (No
> such file or directory)
```

I have been trying to figure this out for hours with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try unzip -l iComputer.jar and make sure your structure is correct. If it all looks good, what is the command you are using to execute this?

Comment: Instead of trying to create a `FileInputStream`, just use `getResourceAsStream` (instead of `getResource`) and use that returned `InputStream`

Comment: @peeskillet, Already considered this an option. For some reason I get an "error error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found"

Comment: @JasonMcD I unzipped and the file location is under res/server.public, I guess the thing I don't understand is where the root of the file path is with getResource() and a .jar file. I don't know if I should be adding more to the file path name or what.

Comment: That's a whole other issue with configuring your keystores. If you're getting this error, then you have over come the file not found exception. I'm sure if you are able to get it to work with FileInputStream, you would have gotten the same error

Comment: @peeskillet, I got it working. Turns out that I was using getResourceAsStream but gathering at the wrong path name? So it wasn't able to write the key to the server. I'm honestly not too sure if this is true. But it works if i have the res folder stored in the package. Final path is "com/ztan222/iComputer/res/server.public. But that's why I was wondering why in the world it was working for a FileInputStream but not a BufferedInputStream. If you want to leave an explained answer below I'll check ya off ;)

Comment: I don't know. Normally, it work for me using `res/client.private`, if using `getClassLoader()`. Using `getClass()`.  I would use `/res/client.private`. I usually never put resources into the Java packaging structure

Comment: You can post how you fixed it. I'm still not even sure what you did :-)

Comment: @peeskillet It works as mentioned above. I still don't get why I was getting "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found" using the BufferedInputStream way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here's what I did to fix the issue (thanks to peeskillet for coming up with the solution). I considered the option of using `getResourceAsStream().` This worked fine in Eclipse, but the problem was that I was getting an error when exporting and running the jar file, `"error error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found".`  It seems as though I was giving it the wrong path.

JSSE's `KeyStore.load()` method will accept **any** type of InputStream as shown in the documentation. It doesn't necessarily *have* to be a FileInputStream.

So, here is my file structure:

```
- iComputer
   - src
        - com
            - ...
        - res
            - server.public
            - client.private
```

Based off of this file structure, the path that works correctly is `"res/server.public"` for both Eclipse and the JAR file. So, here are my revisions to the code from my OP:

```
private static void setupServerKeystore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        mServerKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        mServerKeyStore.load(iComputer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/server.public"), 
                            "pswd".toCharArray());
    }

private static void setupClientKeyStore() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        mClientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );
        mClientKeyStore.load(iComputer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/client.private"),
                               mPassphrase.toCharArray());
}
```

Do yourself a favor, use this as a reference point for where you are putting **your** key file(s). This will save you countless hours trying to figure out why you are getting a `NullPointerException` or `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are not files, and can't be opened with `FileInputStream.` Just get the resource as a stream, and get rid of the `FileInputStream` and all the name processing completely.